# Is it possible to use Citrus Integration test framework to test ASP.Net core application

Tags: asp.net-core, citrus-framework

I have a ASP.net core web application and want to use Citrus framework for integration testing. All the documentation resources say it is meant for JAVA applications. Even an XML based test presentation requires a Java executable test class to run. 
First of all is this possible to achieve?
Second, if it is possible, could someone guide me to the right steps to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Citrus seems just to allow you to "simulate" service endpoints (rest/soap services, tcp/ip connections etc), so yea I guess it would be possible to use it with ASP.NET Core web applications, if its well designed and allow you to change endpoints (rest/soap ui urls) during a test

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to use Citrus Framework for testing application written in languages other than Java. However, the Citrus test cases has to be executed in an Java environment.

What this mean is that you probably want to keep Citrus tests in a Java project separate from your .NET application.

Orchestrating the start and stop of the .NET application before and after the integration testing could however be quite tricky. But even if you don't solve that, Citrus Framework would still be useful for you when developing and executing against your local .NET development environment.